# How to use a cell value in a query?

Tags: google-sheets-query

I'm trying to make a query that is updated automatically by month, to show a summary of values.

I tried using  this code:

=QUERY(Sales!A2:K996,"SELECT A, SUM(B) WHERE G='"&B1&"'  and month(A)+1=' "&X&" '   ")

and it doesn't work.

In the cell X I have the function =MONTH(TODAY()), that returns a number, so if we are in June it will return 6, etc.

But if I use :

=QUERY(Sales!A2:K996,"SELECT A, SUM(B) WHERE G=' "&B1&" '  and month(A)+1=6  ")

the code works.

So, I don't understand why I can call a cell value in the condition G=' "&B1&" ' but not in the condition of the month.

I expected the same output since both values are 6. and the query returns empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am doubtful what you say works actually does (ie further remedial work may be required) but I think the problem you ask about can be fixed by replacing the second `=` in the where clause with `like`.

Comment: That solve the problem, thanks you so much!, works as:

 =QUERY(Ventas!A2:K996,"SELECT* WHERE G='"&B1&"'  and month(A)+1 like '"&E3&"'   ")